# Importing to Gmail, no "Accounts and Import" tab

Tags: gmail, email, import

I have an email account that I would like to import all archived message from into Gmail. The [Gmail help page](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=25413) on this topic says that this is done under the "Accounts and Import" tab in the settings. I don't have an "Accounts and Import" tab in my settings, only an "Accounts" tab and that doesn't have any import options under it. Here's a screenshot of my settings tabs:

[image]

Do other Gmail users have this "Accounts and Import" tab? Any ideas why I do not? This is a regular Gmail account, not a Google Apps for your Domain account.

Comment: If part of a business account then have an admin confirm that "User email uploads" is checked (https://admin.google.com/ac/apps/gmail/setup).

Answer (score 3):

To get mail from other accounts, you can use **Get mail from other accounts** option available in the **Accounts** tab which you have highlighted. More details can be found at [Get mail from other accounts](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&ctx=mail&answer=21288) It will be labled, **Check mail from other accounts (using POP3):**

Comment: It looks like their help pages aren't keeping up with the rapid changes in the app. That tab _used_ to be called `Accounts and Import`.

Comment: +1 even [data liberation seems to be outdated](http://www.dataliberation.org/google/gmail) - looks like **Get mail from other accounts** is the updated version of **Import mail and contacts** except it doesn't import contacts anymore.

Comment: It is not the same at all. Get email from other accounts allows mail to be routed from the other account to gmail. I'm looking to import my contacts from the other account. The original poster is correct. Google's instructions to do this are no longer accurate. From AOL a csv can be exported and then imported into gmail, but it is taking only certain fields. It's taking me a long time to figure out how to format the csv to get it into gmail.

Comment: There was an issue with import and the functionality is currently unavailable. We're working on fixing the problem and hope to bring import back soon.